# Receiving socket data using Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, flask

I have a Flask server which currently display a JSON file. I would like the same server to receive a stream of data via sockets and save it to JSON.
With the help of Stack overflow answers I have drafted the basics, however when data is sent from the client a `404 message` is thrown and is not running the code to process the data(in the example printing `call decoding`).

SERVER

```
from flask import Flask, json, Response
import os
import socket
import threading

app = Flask(__name__)
server_address =  ('', 5001)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    filename = os.path.join(app.static_folder, 'data.json')
    with open(filename) as data:
        data = json.load(data)
    return Response(json.dumps(data), mimetype='application/json')

def launch_socket_server():
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.bind(server_address)
    sock.listen(1)
    print('Listening...')

    while True:
        #Wait for connection
        connection, address = sock.accept()
        print('Connected', address)
    try:
        #Receive data
        while True:
            data = connection.recv(16)
            print(data)
            if data:
                print('call decoding')
    finally:
        #Clean up connection
        connection.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t = threading.Thread(target=launch_socket_server)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, use_reloader=False)
```

CLIENT

```
import socket

server_address =  ('', 5001)
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(server_address)
data = 'Ciao Daniela'
s.sendall(data.encode('utf-8'))
s.close()
```

ERROR ON SERVER CONSOLE

```
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Sep/2019 13:39:35] code 400, message Bad HTTP/0.9 request type ('Ciao')
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Sep/2019 13:39:35] "Ciao Daniela" HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST -
```

Comment: did you run it in console/terminal to see error message ? As I know system can't run two sockets with the same port and Flask uses one socket with port 5000 and you try to run second socket with port 5000. On my computer I get error that this address:port is already used and it can't create socket.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, I just tried with 5000 and 5001 and it works fine.

Comment: @furas I don't get that error when using the same socket. If I use 5000 and then 5001 I get Error 61 connection refused.

Comment: Are you on Windows behind a corporate firewall? Try 127.0.0.1 with the correct port in the browser.

Comment: Sending via client works for me with `server_address =  ('127.0.0.1', 5000)`. With `server_address =  ('', 5000)` I get the message `WinError 10049: The requested address is not valid in its context.`

Answer (score 1):

- Are you on Windows behind a corporate firewall? Try 127.0.0.1 instead of 0.0.0.0 with the correct port in the browser.
- Sending via client works for me with `server_address = ('127.0.0.1', 5000)`. With `server_address = ('', 5000)` I get the message

> WinError 10049: The requested address is not valid in its context

- Use two different ports for the socket and the webserver. I just tried with 5000 and 5001 and it works fine.

Also your indentation is wrong. The socket is stuck in the while loop.

```
while True:
    #Wait for connection
    connection, address = sock.accept()
    print('Connected', address)

    # >>> STUCK HERE <<

try:
    #Receive data
    while True:
        data = connection.recv(16)
        print(data)
        if data:
            print('call decoding')
finally:
    #Clean up connection
    connection.close()
```

Try:

```
while True:
    #Wait for connection
    connection, address = sock.accept()
    print('Connected', address)
    try:
        #Receive data
        while True:
            data = connection.recv(16)
            print(data)
            if data:
                print('call decoding')
    finally:
        #Clean up connection
        connection.close()
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I've made the changes but now get `error 61 - connection refused`. I'm using my mobile as a hostpost I wonder if this could be the cause.

Comment: Can you ping the mobile or from the mobile?

Comment: I'm suspecting that the function `launch_socket_server` is not being run. When I run the server with `flask run` I don't see printing `Listening....`

Comment: Can you just try to run it on your computer and see if everything works locally?

Comment: I did run it locally without being connected to any network, but still get the same 61 error. Thank for helping, it's driving me crazy. I've changed the socket port to 5001 on both client and sever and specified the address as 127.0.0.1 and fixed the indentation issue, but no luck.

Comment: I did run `lsof -Pn -i4` to see if the server port 5001 was open. It doesn't show up in the list. I could see only the webserver `Python    7658 dany    4u  IPv4 0xb21c8999c0898ee9      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:5000 (LISTEN)
` Any thoughts?

Comment: Please put the socket server code in a separate file and start it from there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199606/discussion-between-daniela-and-joe).